# Talend DI - Define filename as variable

Tags: xml, variables, parameters, filenames, talend

My **Talend Job** reads XML files, and convert them to CSV files.
I created a **metadata for Input XML file**. How can I run the Job from Eclipse, sending the filename as parameter, and then receive that filename in my job to read the right XML file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should define XML file name as a context parameter. Later you will set it in Java code, which you will run from eclipse. In a context section(as on next image) add a new variable named "myXmlFile".

[image] 
Then in your tFileInputXML in Filename/InputStream field set context.myXmlFile.

Next step is exporting the job. To do it, you should follow [this](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide53EN/5.2.2+How+to+export+Jobs) instructions. Export it as "Autonomous Job".

Then in your Java project you should add to the classpath a jar generated after job exporting.

To run the job from Java code you should use the next code, in which you will define a context variable and pass it to talend job:

```
String args[] = new String[3];

args[0] = "--context=Default";
args[1] = "--context_param";
args[2] = "myXmlFile=/path/to/your/xml/file";

YourTallendJobClassName job = new YourTallendJobClassName ();
job.runJob(args);
```